# predefine template for new resource/document

Tags: modx

I would like to set the new child documents to default to a set template that is different from the parent.

I've looked through managermanager, but looks like it is unable to do this.
mm_inherit can only inherit from a parent and mm_default does not support template

Comment: It's something I've always wanted to do but not been able to find a way to do it. I'll keep my eye on this thread and see if anyone answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so I finally decided to get my hands dirty and put some code together for this.

Initially I had a a bit of disbelief that this wasn't available already.

so it comes down to two things that are required one is a plugin and the other is a TV

In the tv you select all the templates from the database, which you can use to set child documents. Then in the plugin you use the on document form prerender to see if the child template TV is set, and apply it if it is. Voila.

After working on the plugin for a bit, I was trying to get the @SELECT to work for the tv, I came across a post on modx forums, which lead me to this -> 
http://modxcms.com/extras/package/?package=214

So I ended up replacing my plugin, I wish I came across this sooner  (nevertheless, still good way to learn)